# installing rubymine on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-10.10

I'm new to ubuntu, and installed rubymine as they say on site, after installation I didn't find any app shortcut or new files, so for now I'm running the using the same script I wrote to install it, and I really don't like it, the files are in my downloads folder.

What to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to reach this is to launch File | Create Launcher command. It will register mine command for launching RubyMine. However you can do this manually:
Once you've unpacked RubyMine you can easily create symbolic link using the following command:
sudo ln -s $path_to_installation/bin/rubymine.sh /usr/local/bin/mine.
After executing this command it you'll be able to launch RubyMine using `mine` command.

Answer (score 2):

May have changed in newer versions of RubyMine, but on RubyMine 5.4 on Ubuntu 12.10, I found it under "Tools | Create Command Line Launcher" (Tools, instead of under File).  Wouldn't have found it at all if not for Oleg's suggestion, though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a better question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ but usually you simply want to install to /usr/local/bin so it will become a program that can be run from anywhere on the computer.